# How to run a TypeScript scratch file with imports of a project library using ts-node in WebStorm/IntelliJ?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm, ts-node

I have a TypeScript project in IntelliJ and like to run a TypeScript scratch file to play with some code and libraries. I can run a scratch file without imports using a Node.js run configuration using `--require ts-node/register` as Node Parameters field (see [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-typescript.html#ws_ts_run_debug_server_side_ts_node)). However, if I try to import some project libraries, e.g.

```
import {of} from "rxjs/observable/of";
of('hi').subscribe(console.log);
```

I get `TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript` because `Cannot find module 'rxjs/observable/of'`. I get no error if I use a regular TypeScript file in my project root (instead of a scratch file) or if I use `require` (instead of `import`), i.e.

```
const {Observable, of} = require("rxjs/observable/of");
of('hi').subscribe(console.log);
```

but I'd like to use a scratch file and the `import` syntax. What am I missing in my configuration?

**Edit:** I can not only compile the version with `require` without errors but also execute it without errors.

According to the [help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-typescript.html#ws_ts_run_debug_server_side_ts_node)

> To pass any additional parameters to ts-node (for example, `--project tsconfig.json`), add them in the Application parameters field.

but if I use a non existing path instead of `tsconfig.json`, I get no complaints that the file does not exist. Is the option even taken into account by `ts-node`?

Answer (score -2):

Scratch files are stored in a special location, together with the [IDE preferences](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and not in the project root. That's why the modules installed in the project can't be resolved when transpiling them with `ts-node`.
We do not plan to change where the scratch files are stored as they have to be available to all projects by design.

Comment: The modules can be resolved at runtime if I use `require` (no check at compile time). The compiled scratch file (JavaScript) is placed in the same directory as the scratch file (TypeScript) itself. Why can it not be resolved at compile time if I use `import`? The files are at the same location (outside of the project).

Comment: There are the files `scratch_1.ts` and `scratch_1.js` in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2019.3/scratches/` (Mac OS). I assumed that `scratch_1.js` is the compiled version of `scratch_1.js`, but I was wrong. Nevertheless, it should be possible to tell the compiler in `ts-node` where to look for modules.

Comment: it works with `require` because the IDE sets `NODE_PATH` environment variable to `/path/to/project-root/node_modules` when launching scratches; but the `ts-node` compiler doesn't use this variable to resolve imports

Comment: Why can the TypeScript compiler or language server (`tsserver`) of the IDE editor resolve the imports? No errors are shown in the editor of the scratch file. Does the IDE pass specific parameters, options or environment variables to the compiler for the editor?

Comment: How does the editor of Intellij know how to do code completion in scratch files? How does it resolve the module paths?

Comment: for the IDE, the modules are available as a part of current project